# Can I limit the length of a permuted list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Say I have a a database with the letters A-G:

`elem(a).
 elem(b).
 ...
 elem(g).`

and I want to make a predicate that gives me all possible combinations of those 7 letters in a list, you could do:

```
findall(List, permutation([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],List), X).
```

and X would be a list with all combo's (you don't even need the database for this).

**But**, what I want however is to make a list of only 5 elements long, with the 7 available letters. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Ah, I understood the question differently (limiting the length of combinations, not the number of permutations).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov you are correct in your interpretation in my opinion. I read the question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's `permutation` which does the work here, not `findall`. So the answer is "yes, you just need to write a predicate `combination` such that calling `combination([a,b,c,d,e,f,g], List, 5)` will produce all 5-element sublists of `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]` as separate answers". Some Prolog systems include predicates which would make it quite easy, I don't think SWI-Prolog does.

E.g. http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/lists/subset-2.html would allow you to write

```
combination(SubList, List, Length) :- 
  subset(SubList, List),
  length(SubList, Length).
```

and then

```
?- findall(List, combination([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],List,5), X).
```

Note that SWI-Prolog also provides [`subset/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subset/2), but in a different mode which makes it unusable for this problem (it has `+SubSet`, meaning it can't produce `SubSet`, but needs it to be known). (Plus, the above implementation is quite inefficient.) So I'll leave writing `combination` as an exercise in recursion and arithmetic :)

Comment: Just to be sure, would this be a good `combination`?:                                                       `sbset([],[]).
        sbset([H|L],[H|SL]) :-
        sbset(L,SL).
        sbset(L, [_|SL]) :-
        sbset(L,SL).                                                                                                                            combination(SubList, List, Length) :- 
        sbset(SubList, List),
        length(SubList, Length).`

Comment: I wouldn't consider it good because it's generating all sublists and checking length of each (when used with known `List` and `Length` and variable `SubList`). It works, but you can do better.

Comment: Nevermind, it doesn't even work. I get out of local stack all the time...